# Assigning records to users automatically

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL DB that has multiple tables. Using VIEW I generate a result based on a condition, for example this is my view query:

```
select * from 
 (
  (
   (`customer_info` join `deals`) 
   left join 
   `account_info` 
   on
   (
    (`account_info`.`custID` = `customer_info`.`custID`)
   )
  ) 
  left join `phone_details` 
  on
  (
   (`phone_details`.`dealID` = `deals`.`dealID`)
  )
 ) 
 where 
 (
  (`customer_info`.`custID` = `deals`.`custID`) 
  and
  (`deals`.`precredit` <> 'Complete')
 ) 
 group by 
  `deals`.`dealID` 
 having 
 (
  (100 - ((
   (sum(`phone_details`.`ordered`) - sum(`phone_details`.`received`)) 
   / sum(`phone_details`.`ordered`)) * 100)) 
  >= 60
 )
```

Which pretty much gives me a list of customers that has received atleast 60% of their orders:

```
custID |  customer name  | ordered  | received
1      |  Customer 1     | 5        | 3  
2      |  Customer 2     | 4        | 3
3      |  Customer 3     | 2        | 2
4      |  Customer 4     | 1        | 1
```

Now, what I would like to do is from these result, assign a user to it automatically, let's say I have user1, user2 and user3. So my result would now look like this:

```
custID |  customer name  | ordered  | received  | user
1      |  Customer 1     | 5        | 3         | user1
2      |  Customer 2     | 4        | 3         | user2
3      |  Customer 3     | 2        | 2         | user3
4      |  Customer 4     | 1        | 1         | user1
```

How would I go about doing this scenario?

Comment: I have no idea if this is a good solution (and extreme pseudocode) You could alias `length as count(users)`. Update all such that `user = custId mod length`

Comment: Do you want any fairness between assigned users? Otherwise simply printing `user1` would fulfil the requirements. Do you want the result as a table or should it remain a view? If it is a table, do you create it once or repeatedly, and if repeatedly, can you inspect existing assignments? For a view, I assume that the association between the row and the assigned user should be maintained over multiple executions.

Comment: thank you for the replies. I would to have fairness between users or even an option to assign what percentage of the result each user will get. If possible I would like it to stay as a view and yes users should be maintained over multiple executions.

Comment: if easier from the view results we can create a new table then assign the users automatically just not sure how to do that